# cron job to start docker process and stop docker process

Tags: mongodb, cron, docker

Say I have a mongodb docker process running after the below command:

```
docker run --name my-mongo -d mongo
```

Now I wish I could start this same docker process (same ID) everyday at 6am and stop it everyday at 6pm. Here is what I did in the cron:

```
crontab -e
0 18 * * * /usr/bin/docker stop my-mongo
0 6 * * *  /usr/bin/docker start my-mongo
```

But it didn't run as expected, how to make it works?

**Note:** 
I wish not to runt the `mongo` daemon with cron inside the docker container cause it is very complicated process.

I am using root account and this is CentOS linux.

**Update**

It turns out my `crond` service is not running, after run `service crond start` and everything works.

Comment: check with `docker events` what happened, see the doc http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/events/ and do you get something in /var/log/syslog (or the location of the crontab log on your system) ?

Comment: Does the user whose cron job you've pasted above have privileges to run docker containers? Unless it's root user, please try adding user to docker group using `usermod` and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, my `crond` service is not running after I issued `service crond status` to check. Now after `service crond start` and `chkconfig crond on`, the docker process can be scheduled to start and stop as expected.